# Center DIV in "Miniport" html5 template

Tags: html, css, templates, center

I need some help here.

I found the "Miniport" template by "html5up" and I want to use this template as a base for my future projetc.

The demo can be seen here: http://html5up.net/miniport

On the demo we can see that bellow the website menu is an circular image and next to it is some texts. I need to know how to remove that image and center the texts so the texts can match the rest of the template (the site has the divs centered too).

I dont have much skills on css nor html5. Im a fan and I want to learn.

If anybode can help me, please..

Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

I too am using this template.

In order to remove the image, open the html document.

1. Delete this code that is found between ~line 42—46: (this is what formats and holds your image)

   `<article class="container" id="top">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="4u">
                           <span class="image fit"><img src="images/angela.jpg" alt="" width="118%" height="350" /></span>
         </div>`
2. Reformat the div tag:

   `<div class="8u"> to <div class="container" align="center">`
3. By doing this, you are modifying the style within the html document rather than the css doc. This is good since you do not want to change every div tag in the html doc, just this one. Additionally, adding align="center" helps override most css formatting within your divs. You can use that trick later on in your site.

On a side note, double check that you like the command the contact form uses. I do not, since it opens up my computer's email app rather than directly sending the email through the webpage. That's my next project.

Enjoy!